# PHP PDO prepared statement is not executing

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to learn PDO, go easy on me. I have tried searching and haven't found anything that helps - I'm probably searching for the wrong thing - and I've been scratching my head over this for hours.

I have a PDO prepared statement which doesn't seem to be executing.

I have 3 relevant database tables:

```
create table users (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    username varchar(60),
    password varchar(60)
);

create table stats (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    display_name text,
    short_name varchar(10)
);

insert into stats (display_name, short_name) values ('Magic', 'mag');
insert into stats (display_name, short_name) values ('Attack', 'atk');
insert into stats (display_name, short_name) values ('Defence', 'def');

create table user_stats (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int,
    stat_id int,
    value text /* some none numerical "stats" */
);
```

I've added a few users while testing the registration/login system, the other two tables are as above.

Here is the function to assign a stat to a user:

```
function assignStatToUser($connection, $stat_name, $user_id) {

    $query = $connection->prepare('select id from stats where display_name = :name or short_name = :short');
    $query->bindParam(':name', $stat_name);
    $query->bindParam(':short', $stat_name);
    $query->execute();

    $stat_id = $query->fetchColumn(); // id - $stat_name

    echo $stat_id; // testing

    // var_dump($stat_id);

    // the above works fine

    try {

        $insert = $connection->prepare('insert into user_stats (user_id, stat_id, value) values (:user, :stat, :val)');
        $insert->bindParam(':user', $user_id);
        $insert->bindParam(':stat', /* (int) */ $stat_id);
        $insert->bindParam(':val', '0');
        $insert->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        die($e->getMessage());

    }

}

assignStatToUser($connection, 'def', '10');
```

It is the second query that is not executing, the `insert into` query. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have written and rewritten this, with and without `try...catch`, with backticks around the column names, passing in `$user_id` as a string or an integer.. not sure where I'm going wrong.

**Solution**

My problem was trying to insert a value directly into the `value` column using `bindParam(':val', '0')` - when I changed this line to: `bindParam(':val', $value)` and then the following, it worked - thanks to Zhorov for showing me the way:

```
function assignStatToUser($connection, $stat_name, $user_id, $value) {

    . . . .

}
```

Comment: You know you could this all with one SQL command (using INSERT... SELECT syntax)? You don't need to execute two separate statements

Comment: I tried that previously `insert into user_stats (user_id, stat_id, value) values (:user, (select id from stats where display_name = :name or short_name = :short),  ;0)'`` - it didn't execute and I found it a bit confusing at first so went back to basics for now, until I can get it to work properly, hence the above :/

Comment: Are you not getting any exceptions in your program which would give you a clue about the error? Make sure you're set up for it to throw exceptions by setting the the correct error mode, as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: If you're using insert...select syntax then you don't include the "values" keyword. Take a closer look at examples of the usage. It would be more like `insert into user_stats (user_id, stat_id, value) select :user, id, 0 from stats where display_name = :name or short_name = :short;`. I haven't checked that but that is the general idea. The other fixed values which aren't being read from the table go in as static values in the SELECT. And you should probably put backticks round the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think is your problem is the fact, that the value for your 3rd parameter in `bindParam()` is passed as a value, but it should be a variable. You are directly passing the value, which is not allowed. I'm able to reproduce this error with PHP 7.1.2 and PDO PHP Driver for SQL Server 4.0.3.

You have two options: 1) Define a variable and pass that variable to `bindParam()` or 2) Use `bindValue()` for your 3rd parameter. You also need to include exception handling.

Working example:

```
<?php
# Connection info
$hostname = 'server\instance,port';
$dbname   = 'dbname';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

# Connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server. ".$e->getMessage());
}

# Statement
try {
    $user_id = 123;
    $stat_id = 321;
    $val     = '000';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('insert into user_stats (user_id, stat_id, value) values (:user, :stat, :val)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':stat', $stat_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':val', $val);         // OK, using bindParam() and a variaable
    //$stmt->bindValue(':val', '111');      // OK, using bindValue()
    //$stmt->bindParam(':val', '0');        // Error
    $stmt->execute();
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage() );
}
$stmt = null;

# End
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Comment: THIS! Thank you! You are indeed right - I will edit my existing question and add the current working function to it. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice catch, but the easiest option is to not use parameter binding at all and just pass an array directly to the execute function. Also, it would be good practice to comment the bad code in your answer and uncomment the good code.

Comment: @miken32 Thanks, my mistake. Wrong code is commented.